# Image upload to server using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Hi i am trying to upload image to server, but iam getting error, below is my code**

```
Html code:
 <img  ng-src="{{image_source}}" class="img-responsive" alt="gallery image">
<button type="button" name="yes" class="primary-button" ng-click="tack()">Yes</button>
```

And controller :

```
$scope.tack = function(x) { 
        var imagedata={
            'fileData':$scope.image_source
        }
        console.log(imagedata)

        imageUploadService.uploadImage(imagedata).success(function(response) {
            $scope.image=response;
            console.log($scope.image)
        })
}
```

And service is :

```
app.service('imageUploadService', function ($http,BaseUrl) {

     var Service = function(){
         this.uploadImage = function (imagedata) {

             return $http.post(BaseUrl.url+'eventImageUpload',imagedata);

          };
   }       
  return new Service();

})
```

But iam unable to upload image plz suggest the solution

Comment: It looks like you are trying to use an image tag to do a file upload. IMG tags are for displaying images, not uploading them. You could have a look at this https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload to see a way how to do file uploads

Comment: @MikeKing i am having array of dates, how to convert them to date objects ,any help

Comment: Have a look at either MomentJS or DateJS for date and time manipulation